# RegExp to ignore everything between <code> and <pre> tags

Tags: javascript, regex, nodebb

trying to parse some content (no DOM available - or DOM parser for that matter i.e. jQuery, Cheerio) to replace some words/symbols (basically emotions) by images, BUT would like to ignore everything in between `<code></code>` and `<pre></pre>` this example works great on replacing all the emotions, but doesn't ignore code and pre tags
http://jsbin.com/odARehI/5/edit?js,console

if you run the script, you will see the first print out before the code tag and the second after.

would appreciate another set of eyes on that pattern. Thanks

```
// see link for a list of the emotions to parse
var pattern = /&gt;:\)|\([\w~]+\)|\\[:]?[od]\/|[:;\|bBiIxX8\(\)\]][=\-"^:]?[)>$&|\w\(\)*@#?]?[)>$&|\w\(\)*@#?]/g;
```

I tried few things that didn't work without messing up the original match.

For the **Don't-parse-html-with-regex-police-department**: this is running server side and I do not have the luxury for a DOM parser at the moment.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: for a RegExp solution to ignore `<code>` tags see this neat solution thanks to [github/frissdiegurke](https://github.com/frissdiegurke) in this [commit](https://github.com/frissdiegurke/nodebb-plugin-emoji-skype/commit/5b0252cf99a3dd2d6135843450e5f35705db8e49)

```
/(^|<\/code>)([^<]*|<(?!code>))*(<code>|$)/g
```

Comment: Can you *guarantee* that neither `pre` nor `code` tags will be nested in your input text?

Comment: @icktoofay not really, well, in most cases it's either just a `<code> code here </code>` if in-lined, or if a code block, it looks like that `<pre><code> code here </code></pre>` - but to answer your question, besides that nested pre->code, yea there is no nesting. now that i think about it, ignoring everything in `<code></code>` may be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var co = -1, ce = 0, start=0, result; 
while ( ce != -1 ) {
   co = testString.indexOf('<code', ce);
   if (co > -1) {
     result += parse(testString.substring(start,co), pattern1); 
     start = co+1;
     ce = testString.indexOf('</code>', co + 5);
     if (ce >-1 ){
        start = ce + 7;
        ce = start;
        result += testString.substring(co,ce);
     }
  }
}
result += parse(testString.substring(start), pattern1);
```

console.log(result);

Comment: did some quick [performance testing](http://jsbin.com/enofiluD/1/edit) and this function turned to be the fastest, not by too much. So marking this as the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Without DOM parsing you are going to have edge cases which will fail.  But, this should work for you.

Given this HTML:

```
Hello :) <pre>Wassup :)</pre> Maybe :) <code>:) Foo</code> :) Bar
```

Use this code:

```
var blocks = [];
html = html.replace(/(?:<pre>.*?<\/pre>|<code>.*?<\/code>)/g, function (match) {
    blocks.push( match );
    return '__BLOCK__';
});

html = html.replace(/:\)/g, 'SMILE');

html = html.replace(/__BLOCK__/g, function () {
    return blocks.shift();
});
```

Which produces:

```
Hello SMILE <pre>Wassup :)</pre> Maybe SMILE <code>:) Foo</code> SMILE Bar
```

Just adjust the `/:\)/g` replace to work however you need it.

Comment: I'd be a lot happier with this solution if `__BLOCK__` was dynamically selected to be a string not appearing in the input.

Comment: That's a brilliant answer.

Answer (score 3):

Guess you're using nodejs or a recent javascript engine (for "map" & "split" implementations), so you can do this:

```
function replaceSpecial(str, pattern, replacement) {
  var REG = /(<code>.*?<\/code>)|(<pre>.*?<\/pre>)/i;
  return str.split(REG).map(function(s) {
    if ('' + s !== s)
      return '';
    if (s.match(REG))
      return s;
    return s.replace(pattern, replacement);
  }).join('');
}
```

Example:

```
replaceSpecial("hey :) <code>:)</code> :'( <pre> :'( :)</pre>", /(:\))|(:'\()/, function(s) {
  switch(s) {
    case ":)":
      return '<img src="smile.gif" />';
    case ":'(":
      return '<img src="cry.gif" />';
  }
})
```

Will return:

```
"hey <img src="smile.gif" /> <code>:)</code> <img src="cry.gif" /> <pre> :'( :)</pre>"
```

---

Or easier if you just want to replace an emoticon:

```
replaceSpecial("hey :) <code>:)</code>", ":)", '<img src="smile.gif" />')
```

=>

```
"hey <img src="smile.gif" /> <code>:)</code>"
```

Comment: For others to not reproduce my mistake: the parenthesis in the example are important if you want to keep the separator in the split array :)